# Android put link like text that when pressed displays a pop up

Tags: android

I have some text views in an linear layout in my android application. Next to them I want to put a small question mark of the form [?], that when tapped displays a popup with some information. I could do this with a button but it would be very big.

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the question mark in a new TextView, and set a click listener via the `onClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)`. From there you could use the `getId()` method to determine the question mark that was called. Then, you could use a switch statement, to split your programflow, and to whatever you want inside the switch statement.

TextView in the Android Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `TextView` with the text `?`.

- set the width to `wrap_content`
- handle the `onClick` event to open the popup

Answer (score 1):

use `TextView` to show  **?**  and use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) for showing message as on textview click :

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    t.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // OPEN PopupWindow HERE
    }
```

and how we create popupwindow you can see this tutorial for help:

[Example of using PopupWindow](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html)